# How to use IN prepared statement with single variable in typeorm

Tags: sql, typescript, typeorm

I have a .sql file containing a query such as

```
SELECT * WHERE id IN ($1)
```

The sql query is read and passed into a typeorm query with an array of parameters.

```
const result = await this.entityManager.query(myQuery, parameters);
```

I would like to have `parameters` be an array with a single value that would be a string concatenation of all the ids I want to find.
This would allow me to use my sql file no matter the number of ids I want to filter by.

I have tried formatting `parameters` in such a way that I can have `$1` only no matter the number of items in my array:

```
const ids = ['1', '2', '3'];

const parameters = [ids.join("', '")];
```

or

```
const parameters = ["'" + ids.join("', '") + "'"];
```

etc

I have not found a syntax that works.

Is this feasible somehow ?

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have replaced the IN ($1) by  `= ANY($1)` and am now passing the ids as an array. This works as I intend.

```
SELECT * WHERE id = ANY($1);
```

```
const ids = ['1', '2', '3'];
const result = await this.entityManager.query(myQuery, [ids]);
```